# Computing the Chern class for a flat line bundle using the holonomy group?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a Riemann surface of genus $g \geq 2$. I would like to consider flat line bundles on $X$. Flat line bundles can be identified with representations $\pi_1(X) \rightarrow U(1)$. From Chern-Weil theory it is known that the Chern class of such a line bundle vanishes in rationally. 
On the other hand, one may construct from each representation 
$\rho: \pi_1(X) \rightarrow U(1)$ a line bundle $E_{\rho}$  and a mapping which associates $\rho$ with $c_1(E_{\rho})$. This mapping is a homomorphism where the kernel of this homomorphism detects trivial line bundles and the image the Chern classes.

Moreover, it is known from the theorem of Ambrose-Singer that the holonomy group of a flat bundle is discrete.

So my question's are:
Given the discrete holonomy group of a flat line bundle, is it possible to compute its Chern class?
More generally, is this possible for flat complex vector bundles on Riemann surfaces?

Another question which is related:
How much of the topological information can one detect from the holonomy bundle associated to the holonomy group?

Comment: For one of your questions, the answer is simple.
The second integral cohomology of Riemann surface is torsion free,
so if $c_1$ vanishes rationally, it vanishes. This applies
to flat bundles.

Comment: For computing integral first Chern classes of flat line bundles, see my question here : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/56103/first-chern-class-of-a-flat-line-bundle